# Blur one colour in paint.net

Tags: paint.net

Is it possible to blur/smudge only one colour in paint.net?

e.g. blurring a red box with a thick black border so that the red blurs into the black but the outside of the border remains sharp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

magic wand the red (possibly with global as opposed to contiguous flood mode - that's the lightbulb on the top bar), copy, paste in new a layer, then run some kind of blurring filter on the red on the new filter. reduce the opacity of the layer to taste.

Comment: is it possible to do this for ALL the red boxes in an image? i have over 100

Comment: yes. magic wand, then switch flood mode to global - it will select all areas of the same colour, or close enough based off your tolerance level.

Comment: thanks, thats got the selecting. However when i select blur it only blurs within the selection. How can i blur with big black border of the red box? I want to make the black border smaller and the red bit bigger. hope that makes sense

Comment: select the area. copy it. paste it in a new layer. blur the NEW layer. that way you'll blur the whole thing, but only the red bits.